# excluding classes from hot-reloading in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm experimenting with the Play Framework and really like the experience thus far!
Especially hot-reloading is a huge time saver.

However, I want to be able to exclude some class-instances from hot-reloading on a code-change. (For example I have configured some repositories which need a pretty long time to initialize and I'm sure the code of these repositories won't change) .

How would I indicate which classes / packages are disabled from hot-reloading?

Thanks, 
Geert-Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to have this code as a separate project in your IDE, and create a JAR file. Place this JAR file in the play `lib` folder when you have compiled and updated the necessary code. You could even do this reasonably straight forward with an ant script to compile the set of classes, and drop it into the `lib` folder.

There are other ways to approach this, but as far as I know, it would involve changing, or extending the Play framework, and I think this is overkill for what you need.

Comment: Yeah alright that makes sense thanks. I would have liked to see a way to do this out-of-the-box within the Play Framework itself though (using a @dontreload annotation on the class or something).

Comment: Yeah, I thought that is where you were going with it. There is no annotation of that nature that I have seen in the codebase. Its the first time I have heard this requirement, so doubt it would be on a roadmap for the next version of Play.